# log4j2 - как в файле конфигурации прописать динамически меняющееся название директории?

Tags: java, log4j2

**Дано:**
В директории services_desk \ _result должна появляться папка с названием формата "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", в которой будут сохраняться результаты работы программы и лог-файл "_results.txt". Важно - всё в одну папку, её название надо формировать динамически.

Я сделяля (код из разных методов, лишнее опускаю):

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
System.setProperty("LOG_DIR", "services_desk\\_result\\" + sdf.format(new Date()));
Path resultDirectory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("LOG_DIR"));
resultDirectory.toFile().mkdir();
```

В результате я создаю папку, в которую программа сохраняет результаты.

**Найти:**
Как мне в xml-конфиге прописать использование этой папки для сохранения лог-файла? Примеры не ищутся, везде используется статичный путь. Свои варианты кидать нет смысла, они методом тыка и совсем-совсем нерабочие.

Comment: `в которой будут сохраняться результаты работы программы` результаты работы программы не стоит хранить в папке с логами, лучше разделать, чтобы потом не запутаться

Comment: Это не совсем обычные логи, это человеко-читаемые логи для юзера, который смотрит лог-файл и анализирует результаты работы программы (это тоже файлы). Бизнес-задача ровно такая, увы (или ура).

Comment: Не знаю как это сделать в xml, но может проще не в нем это делать? Вы можете в xml конфиге задать путь к логу через jvm property. На старте приложения заполнять эту jvm property текущим временем, но делать это обязательно перед первым вызовом log4j.